# How secure are the default, randomized passwords that ISP routers come with?

Tags: passwords, wifi, isp, default-password

Did a little searching an could not find an answer to this. A lot of ISPs these days are providing combination router/modem units, and they come with a pre-configured password that is a random string of letters and numbers, such as `1kd94nc9`. Are these passwords reasonably secure, or should the end user change it to their own custom password (ignoring the fact that these can be hard for someone to remember)?

Comment: There is no universal answer. An ISP may or may not have used a process that generates unpredictable passwords. They may or may not store a copy of your password. If you somehow knew the answer for one company, that wouldn't mean you could conclude what a different company does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're often not as random as they might appear. The forums posts listed [here](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-7691.html) show many examples of researchers reverse-engineering the algorithms used to generate default router passwords - sometimes, even by disassembling the firmware.

Many manufacturers assume that no one will go to such trouble. These manufacturers often rely on obscurity, using algorithms that are only pseudo-random, and/or derived from the MAC address or other non-random information.

This varies by manufacturer and model, of course - but since it's often very hard to tell, you're almost always better off changing to something that you *know* is random, and of sufficient length to be beyond run-of-the-mill bruteforce capabilities - say, 15 characters random mixed-case alphanumeric+specials (or often better, the equivalent entropy in a randomly-generated passphrase that's easy to type).

Answer (score -1):

It is best practice to change the default password of all devices that you use once you finish set up. It is even better to change them periodically following a practice of "cyber/digital hygiene".
Regarding the hard to remember part, may I suggest pass phrases instead? Pass phrases is a series of common words (QuickFoxLazy) that actually increase complexity of the password and are easy to remember by creating some bizarre story behind the scene.